Alt + Tab to a specific application in automated way in Powershell
I am using the below command for alt+tab
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{TAB}")

But depending on scope it randomly selects an application.
My requirement is to alt+tab to PowerBI desktop application irrespective of any number of open windows.
Is it even possible to do that via powershell?
Note : I tried Get-process but it is showing me all processes and not specific to the alt+tab ones. And as of now I didnt see any parameter to pass the process ID to alt+tab to that
